# Drupal Fields added using form_alter to be shown in node preview

Tags: drupal, preview

I have added Form fields to a content type using form alter in drupal. Is there any way to see these fields in node preview? I can only see the fields that are added using cck in node preview.

Comment: The API changes considerably between major versions. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Up until Drupal 6, implement [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6), passing `'view'` as argument for `$op`. In Drupal 7, implemente [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7).

Comment: That worked.. Thanks.. Can i know how these values can be assigned to the fields in preview.

Answer (score 0):

The hooks called when a node is viewed are the ones reported by Oswald.

The only function that knows when a node is being previewed is [node_preview()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_preview/6), or [theme_node_preview()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/theme_node_preview/6) that is invoked by `node_preview()` using the following code:

```
// Drupal 6.
if (!form_get_errors()) {
  $cloned_node = drupal_clone($node);
  $cloned_node->build_mode = NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW;
  $output = theme('node_preview', $cloned_node);
}

// Drupal 7.
if (!form_get_errors()) {
  $node->in_preview = TRUE;
  $output = theme('node_preview', array('node' => $node));
  unset($node->in_preview);
}
```

[theme_node_preview()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/theme_node_preview/6), then calls [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/6) using the following code:

```
// Drupal 6.
$output .= '<h3>' . t('Preview trimmed version') . '</h3>';
$output .= node_view(drupal_clone($node), 1, FALSE, 0);
$output .= '<h3>' . t('Preview full version') . '</h3>';
$output .= node_view($node, 0, FALSE, 0);

// Drupal 7.
$elements = node_view(clone $node, 'teaser');
$trimmed = drupal_render($elements);
$elements = node_view($node, 'full');
$full = drupal_render($elements);
```

As `node_view()` invokes `hook_nodeapi()` (or `hook_node_view()`), those hook implementations are able to know if the node is being previewed checking for `$node->build_mode` (or `$node->in_preview`). In Drupal 6, the module should check `$node->build_mode` is equal to `NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW`.